# How to assign address to a function pointer if parameters is specified?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Before that I used such huge things:

```
int* ShowPopUpMessage = (int*)0x004837F0; //declare
((int (__cdecl*)(const char *, char))ShowPopUpMessage)("You see this message!", 0); //call
```

ehm, I think is no need to tell it's kinda confusing.

Now I want to declare normal function pointer like that:

```
int *ShowPopupMessage(const char *, char);
```

To be able call that function like that:

```
ShowPopupMessage("asd", 0);
```

But I can't assign function address to that pointer. I tried:

```
int *ShowPopupMessage(const char *, char) = (int*)0x004837F0; //error: function "ShowPopupMessage" may not be initialized

//then this
int *ShowPopupMessage(const char *, char);
ShowPopupMessage = 0x004837F0; //nope

ShowPopupMessage = (int*)0x004837F0; //nope

*ShowPopupMessage = 0x004837F0; //nope

*ShowPopupMessage = (int*)0x004837F0; //nope
```

uhh. Any other ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should read the compiler's diagnostics even with subsequent attempts of solving a compile error. I *really* doubt that it ever said "nope."

A `typedef` is especially useful when you want to declare a function (or a function pointer) returning a function pointer. In a simple function pointer type expression it doesn't buy you much, as you really only need to remember the parenthesis when you write one, like this:

```
int *ShowPopupMessage(const char*, char); // a function declaration
int (*ShowPopupMessage)(const char*, char); // a function pointer definition
```

Both are an easy read for C++ programmers.

In your case, a `typedef` might be preferable (as you need to use the type twice), but as you 
seem to have trouble understanding acceptable implicit conversions, I'm not going to hide the problem behind a `typedef` curtain.

In the examples above, you're mostly only changing the left-hand side of things. C++ does not allow implicit conversions of integer types to (any) pointer types, and in a similar fashion, it doesn't allow implicit conversions of object pointer types to function pointer types. If you want to interpret an integer as a function pointer, you need a cast -- and not just any cast, but a `reinterpret_cast` to a function pointer type.

```
// this is OK (with the cast), but ShowPopupMessage is not a function pointer,
// but a pointer to int
int *ShowPopupMessage = (int*)0xDEADBEEF;

// this is incorrect, as C++ does not allow implicit conversions from
// object pointers to function pointers
int (*ShowPopupMessage)(const char*, char) = (int*)0xDEADBEEF;

// this is OK (assuming you know what you're doing with 0xDEADBEEF)
int (*ShowPopupMessage)(const char*, char) =
        (int(*)(const char*, char))0xDEADBEEF;

// this is preferable in C++ (but it's not valid C)
int (*ShowPopupMessage)(const char*, char) =
        reinterpret_cast<int(*)(const char*, char)>(0xDEADBEEF);

// (this is a possibility in C++11)
#include <functional>
std::function<int(const char*, char)> ShowPopupMessage =
        reinterpret_cast<int(*)(const char*, char)>(0xDEADBEEF);
// it's used in much the same way as function pointers are
// i.e. you call it like you always call them: ShowPopupMessage("", ' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a typedef:

```
typedef int (*funptr)(const char *, char);
funptr ShowPopupMessage;

ShowPopupMessage = (funptr) your_address_goes_here;
ShowPopupMessage("hello", 0);
```

Comment: thanks, this is really working. I just hoped to assign address right at declaration. to sad, but this is easer anyway :D

Comment: You can do `funptr ShowPopupMessage = (funptr) your_address_goes_here;`

Comment: now it compiles. i tried that before, but it gave error like address can't be converted to funptr. However, now everything is fine!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
{
    typedef int (*funcPtr)(const char *, char);

    funcPtr func = (funcPtr) 0x004837F0;

    func("asd", 0);
}
```

Comment: ehm... it's not compiles in vc++ 2010 express. same error about funct may no be initialized and address can't be converted to funcPtr

Comment: @Kosmos, it should now, I had *(funcPtr) instead of (*funcPtr), thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a function declaration, not a function pointer declaration:

```
int *ShowPopupMessage(const char *, char);
```

Use a `typedef` to create a function pointer:

```
typedef int (*func_t)(const char*, char);
```

which can be used:

```
int _my_pop_up_one(const char* a_msg, char a_ch)
{
    std::cout << "one: " << a_msg << ", " << a_ch << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int _my_pop_up_two(const char* a_msg, char a_ch)
{
    std::cout << "two: " << a_msg << ", " << a_ch << "\n";
    return 0;
}

func_t show = _my_pop_up_one;
show("hello", 'a');
show = _my_pop_up_two;
show("hello", 'a');
```

As this is C++ worth mentioning the existence of [functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) (and `std::string` instead of `char*`), that allow an object to called as it it were an ordinary function:

```
struct func_t
{
    virtual int operator()(const std::string&, char) const = 0;
};

struct my_pop_up_one : func_t
{
    int operator()(const std::string& a_msg, char a_ch) const
    {
        std::cout << "one: " << a_msg << ", " << a_ch << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
};

struct my_pop_up_two : func_t
{
    int operator()(const std::string& a_msg, char a_ch) const
    {
        std::cout << "two: " << a_msg << ", " << a_ch << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
};

void display_pop_up(const func_t& a_func)
{
    a_func("hello", 'a');
}

display_pop_up(my_pop_up_one());
display_pop_up(my_pop_up_two());
```

Comment: whoops :P thanks, really i tried to declare function, instead of function pointer